# fromJSON reading a list of characters

Tags: r, jsonlite

This is a follow-up from [doing multiple fromJSON queries (jsonlite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645140/doing-multiple-fromjson-queries-jsonlite?noredirect=1#comment84288654_48645140). Not sure if it's ok to post separate but related questions.

following @parfait 's suggestion, I tried to create a list of URLs in a list so that fromJSON can be applied to it. However I faced an error

```
library(jsonlite)
library(BBmisc)
library(readxl)
# reading an excel file with 1 column of URLs
sample_postal_code <- read_excel("~/Desktop/sample postal code.xlsx")
```

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BC2JHKg03DReFdCN-Ru-cTrxXXOZ1ZTw

```
dataset <- convertRowsToList(sample_postal_code[-1])
dataset <- unlist(dataset,recursive = F)

json_list2 <- lapply(dataset, function(i) fromJSON(i)$results)
=> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.
```

For the record, the following code worked:

```
 library(jsonlite)

x1 <- as.character("https://developers.onemap.sg/commonapi/search?searchVal=revenue&returnGeom=Y&getAddrDetails=Y&pageNum=1)")
x2 <- as.character("https://developers.onemap.sg/commonapi/search?searchVal=airport&returnGeom=Y&getAddrDetails=Y&pageNum=1)")
url_list <- list(x1,x2)

json_list <- lapply(url_list, function(i) fromJSON(i)$results)
df = Reduce(function(...) merge (... , all=T),json_list)
```

I notice under the drop-down in url_list that it has

```
: chr "https://developers.onemap.sg/commonapi/search?searchVal=revenue&returnGeom=Y&getAddrDetails=Y&pageNum=1)"

: chr "https://developers.onemap.sg/commonapi/search?searchVal=airport&returnGeom=Y&getAddrDetails=Y&pageNum=1)"
```

then x1 and x2 below, while dataset has:

```
1 : chr "https://..."
2 : chr "https://..."
```

and so on. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: http 400 error is a "bad request" error, so without seeing a sample of your dataset it is difficult to provide much assistance.

Comment: hi @Dave2e I've added the sample. Thanks.